# Checking for a memory leak?

Tags: c++

For my code, expand is to double the capacity of the vector. It should dynamically reallocate memory for the dynamically allocated array and update the value of capacity while not creating a memory leak.

I was wondering how you would check for a memory leak as my testing doesn't show execution times in Visual Studio.

```
void IntVector::expand(){
    cap = cap * 2;
    int *data2;
    data2 = data;
    IntVector::~IntVector();
    data = new int[cap];
    data = data2;
    delete data2;
}
```

header (I understand that you aren't supposed to be using namespace std).

```
#ifndef INTVECTOR_H
#define INTVECTOR_H

using namespace std;
class IntVector{
private:
    unsigned sz;
    unsigned cap;
    int *data;
public:
    IntVector();
    IntVector(unsigned size);
    IntVector(unsigned size, int value);
    unsigned size() const;
    unsigned capacity() const;
    bool empty() const;
    const int & at (unsigned index) const;
    const int & front() const;
    const int & back() const;
    ~IntVector();
    void expand();

};

#endif
```

main file

```
#include "IntVector.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;



IntVector::IntVector(){
    sz = 0;
    cap = 0;
    data = NULL;
}

IntVector::IntVector(unsigned size){
    sz = size;
    cap = size;
    data = new int[sz];
    *data = 0;
}

IntVector::IntVector(unsigned size, int value){
    sz = size;
    cap = size;
    data = new int[sz];
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
        data[i] = value;
    }
}

unsigned IntVector::size() const{
    return sz;
}

unsigned IntVector::capacity() const{
    return cap;
}

bool IntVector::empty() const{
    if(sz > 0){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}

const int &IntVector::at(unsigned index) const{
    if(index > sz){
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        return data[index];
    }
}

const int &IntVector::front() const{
    return data[0];
}

const int &IntVector::back() const{
    return data[sz];
}

IntVector::~IntVector(){
    delete data;
}

void IntVector::expand(){
    cap = cap * 2;
    int *data2;
    data2 = data;
    IntVector::~IntVector();
    data = new int[cap];
    data = data2;
    delete data2;
}
```

Edit::

```
void IntVector::expand(){
    cap = cap * 2;
    int *data2 = data;
    data = new int[cap];
    delete[] data2;
    delete data2;
}
```

Comment: Why do you do `data = data2;`? That's going to leave `data` pointing at the old data which you then destroy.

Comment: You also need to use `delete[]` to deallocate an array. And you need to implement a copy constructor/assignment operator.

Comment: I was planning on storing the local address of the new array to not lose the old one.

Comment: Find all `= new` and replace with `make_unique`, `make_shared`, or `vector`

Comment: void IntVector::expand(){
    cap = cap * 2;
    int *data2 = data;
    data = new int[cap];
    delete[] data2;
    delete data2;
}

Does that improve upon the original error?  *Edit: posted my edit in the original post.

Comment: @MooingDuck you seem to be missing the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These 2 lines:

```
data = new int[cap];
data = data2;
```

Allocate an array of ints, and then immediately override the pointer leading to it, thereby losing that allocated memory for ever. That's a memory leak.

Using valgrind or similar tools should lead to these errors very easily.

Answer (score 1):

To test for memory leaks in Visual Studio:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
```

and this next line will automatically display a memory-leak report at every place in your code where an application exit occurs.

```
_CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
```

---

***Edited** for maxywb*

Comment: You might want to mention that this is Visual Studio specific. I know the OP is looking for VS solutions, but it's polite to say it.

Answer (score -1):

I use task manager from windows.

in windows 8:
Details tab -> right click on a column and 'select columns' -> GDI objects

Keep an eye on this column, if this keeps rising while it shouldn't then you have a leak.

Comment: That only identifies a very small number of memory leaks, and does not find the leak in the question